# Defense of Others: Using Force Against a Third Party Who Impedes Life-Saving Measures

Tags: precedent, comparative-law, defense-of-others

Can "defense of others" be invoked as a legal defense when a third party prohibits access to life-saving measures for a person? Assume person A's life is in imminent danger. Person B's life-saving measures are impeded by person C. I am interested in understanding the legal principles and considerations that apply in such a situation and how the use of force to ensure the person can receive life-saving help may be assessed. US based answers and mention of precedents are appreciated, and it would also be great to contrast those with European (e.g. German, French) legislation.

Comment: Is C impeding the lifesaving deliberately?  Do they have a good reason for doing so?  Is B aware of this, or reasonably should be aware?  Is the force of a kind that could injure C?  Is it deadly force?

Comment: One example which would make the question more specific are road blocks by protestors. Assume C denies passage of B, who is a doctor/ambulance and A needs urgent medical attention. Or maybe an ambulance (B) tries to reach the hospital with A inside. To what degree could B or bystanders use force if C refuses to let the ambulance pass?